# How do I export animation with inherit rotation turned off?

Tags: animation, export

I have two bones with parent/child relation ship.

Child bone does not inherit rotation from Parent because I turned it off (unchecked the *Inherit Rotation*) as I don't want the child to rotate with parent.

This works perfectly in Blender. But when I export to FBX (with Baked Animation) to use in another software, the rotation is inherited.

How do I export the animation with inherit rotation turned off?

I've tried turning it on and adding a constraint to limit rotation but it has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problems comes from an "inherit rotation" behaviour of the destination rig. If you baked all animation infos (loc and rot) you can break the parent-child relationship of the destination rig, and everything should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Change the rig.  Assuming Child's head lays at the position of Parent's tail, and the Child isn't inheriting any scaling, give Child a Copy Location constraint targeting Parent, with head/tail set to 1.0, then unparent Child.  Rebake the animation with Visual Keying and Clear Constraints.

Option 2: Recalculate your rotation by using an interim bone.  Duplicate Child, enable inherit rotation on the duplicate, then give the duplicate a Copy Transforms constraint targeting the original Child.  Bake your animation (with Visual Keying and Clear Constraints.)  Copy/paste the duplicate's keyframes onto the original Child bone.  Enable inherit rotation on the original Child, then delete your duplicate bone.